# Commit message for lots of files

Tags: git

If I modify 10 files (uncommitted) and I want to commit those 10 files (modified), is a commit message given for each file or one message for all files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not think in terms of files; it thinks in terms of *snapshots of the entire repository*. When you create a commit, you are creating a new snapshot of the repository, based on the files which you "stage" with `git add` (or in other ways).

It's worth mentioning here that git doesn't think in terms of *changes* either, so *every* file in your repository is part of that commit, even the ones you *didn't* change. However, commands like `git log` are smart enough to know what you mean by "the history of this file", and skips over the commits where that file is identical to the previous commit.

In short: the commit message applies to the whole commit, which applies to the whole repository.

Answer (score 1):

A commit is a logical entity that describes a change you want to make. Assuming the changes in all these files are part of the same logical change, they should all be included in a single commit.

Comment: Technically, a commit in git doesn't refer to a _change_ at all, it refers to a _state_. Changes are reconstructed on demand by _comparing_ commits. The difference doesn't matter for this question, but it does for other cases, so is worth always being clear about.

Answer (score 1):

If you worked on a same task in all these files then you can add them simply by **git add .** and then give your message by **git commit -m "you message"**.
if you have done multiple tasks then add you desired files by giving their path in command **git add "path to file"** and then add message for given file **git commit -m "your message"**.

Comment: Excellent advice, for when to choose just one commit or multiple commits.

Answer (score 0):

One message for all assuming you have `git add` those 10 files from working directory to the staging area.